# Как поменять столбцы и строки местами в двумерном массиве?

Tags: c#

как выполнить замену соответствующей строки на столбец и наоборот?
Решено, получилось:

```
using System;
class ForDemo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] nums = new int[3, 3];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[,] array = new int[3, 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                nums[i, j] = rnd.Next(21);
                Console.Write(nums[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = nums[i, j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            array[i, 0] = nums[0, i];
            array[i, 1] = nums[1, i];
            array[i, 2] = nums[2, i];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            array[i, 0] = nums[0, i];
            array[i, 1] = nums[1, i];
            array[i, 2] = nums[2, i];
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++)
        {
            array[i, 0] = nums[0, i];
            array[i, 1] = nums[1, i];
            array[i, 2] = nums[2, i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Результат: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: сами что то пробовали?

Comment: Неужели из топика-дубликата ничего лучше не выбрали? Что будете делать, если матрица будет 2х2 или 5х5?

Comment: можно и усовершенствовать